# Android custom view get width once

Tags: android

I have a custom view in an Android project and in that custom view, I want to draw a bitmap that's about 1/3th the size of the view element.

I use the following code

```
Bitmap bigIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
Bitmap icon =   Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bigIcon, newWidth, newHeight, false);
```

width `newWidth` and `newHeight` being 1/3th of the view's width and height.

The problem is now that if I want to get the view's width or height, I'd have to get it in the `onMeasure` or `onDraw` method. And I'd really prefer not to scale it every single frame (the `bigIcon` is loaded only once in the constructor). The `createScaledBitmap` needs also to be called only once but the constructor is too soon since the View is not yet created.

So the question: how can I access the view's width and height (knowing that the view's size doesn't change)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can accomplish what you want by overriding your custom View's [onSizeChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) method.

Here, you can calculate the dimensions of your bitmap based on the View's dimensions only when the size has actually changed.